# Which android sensor will give ma data if I move phone like this...?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am getting start sensor. I want to know which sensor in android will help me. and how? If I want to know when my phone moves like this.. [Anim Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN91k-vKtAo) .
Can any one please help me?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? Can you help me out on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997669/android-acceleration-down-smash) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Acceleration sensor and Orientation sensor as well to accuratelly recognize the move described in your video.

So, I would recommend to collect the data from mentioned sensors and describe movement (acceleration and orientation should have separate 3D functions) with few mathematical functions/graphs. Then , within certain accuracy, check whether repeated move matches expected behaviour on all axis.

You will need this for reference on the axis:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

Looks like no change (or very small) should occur on Y-axis to describe move from your video.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me check it out.

Comment: That the point what I was looking for. I will implement some function to find the require movement of the phone. Thanks

Comment: @Zelimir Can you help me out on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997669/android-acceleration-down-smash) please?

Comment: Hey, looks like you have some useful answers on this question.